# React combine JSX element following by a JS instruction?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Here is my code, I think I need an operator to join both but I don't know what

```
<ul>
{suggestionList.length ? 
    <li className="header">Suggestions</li>
    // <--- compiler says error from here
    suggestionList.map((item) =>
        <li
           key={item.id}
           onClick={this.handleSuggestClick(item)}
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.label }}
        />
    )
 : <li><em>No item found</em></li>
}
</ul>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot scoping the `.map` expression

```
<ul>
{suggestionList.length ?
// v React.Fragment
  <>
    <li className="header">Suggestions</li>
//  v start scope {}    
    {suggestionList.map((item) =>
        <li
           key={item.id}
           onClick={this.handleSuggestClick(item)}
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.label }}
        />
    )}
 </>
 : <li><em>No item found</em></li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: `<React.Fragment>` combining with `{}` helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add curly brackets `{}` between two JSX tags to add JS code like so:

```
<ul>
{suggestionList.length ? 
    <li className="header">Suggestions</li>
    // <--- compiler says error from here
    {suggestionList.map((item) =>
        <li
           key={item.id}
           onClick={this.handleSuggestClick(item)}
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.label }}
        />
    )}
 : <li><em>No item found</em></li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wrap in one section like template and add {}

Try this, tell me if it work :)

```
<ul>
  {suggestionList.length ?
    <template>
      <li className="header">Suggestions</li>
      {suggestionList.map((item) =>
        <li
          key={item.id}
          onClick={this.handleSuggestClick(item)}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.label }}
        />
      )}
    </template>
    : <li><em>No item found</em></li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Syntax correct. But the page doesn't generate the header "Suggestion"